# Meet or meet us, email

Tags: word-difference

I would like to know what is the best or correct answer.

What about meeting us next week?
What about meet next week?
What about if we meet next week?

Answer (score 1):

> What about meeting us next week?

This is acceptable **informal** speech. Normal for a brief email. You could also say "*how about...*"

> What about meet next week?

This is incorrect. You could say "*what about meeting next week*", similar to the previous sentence but omitting the word "us".

> What about if we meet next week?

Also acceptable, informally. You could also use "how" and omit the "if" as in "*How about we meet next week?*"